# Are "in place" Cython functions possible?

Tags: python, cython, python-c-api, cythonize

Suppose I have the C function which returns `void`

```c
void mysub_wrapper(int *a, int *b)
{
  *b = *a + 1;
}
```

Can I make a wrapper with Cython which passes `a` and `b` by reference:

```py
cdef extern void mysub_wrapper(int *a, int *b)

def mysub(int a, int b):
  mysub_wrapper(&a, &b)
```

Such that it can be called in python with

```py
a = 1
b = 0
mysub(a, b)
```

In other words, can I do the calculation "in place".

Comment: Python doesn't have the notion of passing variables by reference. In-place operations are only possible on mutable containers, such as lists and dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. A `cdef`-ed function could do it (because it would work solely with C level types, not Python types), but Python level `int`s are immutable (so you can't *actually* modify them in-place, you must rebind them to a new `int` object), and Python has no concept of pass-by-reference (it's pass-by-object-reference, which roughly translates to passing a copy of the pointer, without copying what it points to), so the moment you call `mysub(a, b)` it makes aliases referring to the same `1` and `0` object that `mysub` receives, but it loses all connection to the `a` and `b` outside the function.

Regardless, it's horribly unPythonic to do this. If you must do it, [just have the wrapper allocate its own C level `int` and pass a pointer to it to the underlying C function, then return the value after it's been reassigned to match Python behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47041653/364696). The performance cost is meaningless (rewrapping from C `int` to Python `int` is chump change in overall overhead of Python), and returning new values rather than modifying function arguments in place, even when it's possible, is much cleaner, less error-prone, and more Pythonic style.